# All methods in onClick are executed without waiting for a larger function to return in Android

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick

I am trying to 'Start' a function on button click, then I change its text to 'Stop'. I am calling that function and on return I want to set it again to 'Start', but I do not see 'Stop' text even when the function is executing. Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (btn_workout.getText().equals("START")) {
            btn_workout.setText("STOP");
            startWorkout();
            btn_workout.setText("START");
        }
        else{
            btn_workout.setText("START");
        }
    }
```

Here is Workout function used above:

```
public void  startWorkout() {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.image);
        ArrayList<String> workoutIds = getWorkout();
        int[] workouts = new int[14];
        int i=0;

        for (String id: workoutIds){
            Log.i(WORKOUT, "startWorkout: " + id);
            String mDrawableName = "hiit" + id;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable",
                    getContext().getPackageName());
            workouts[i++] = resID;
            Log.d(WORKOUT, "startWorkout: " + resID);
        }
//        Uncomment Below line for testing
        int[] workouts1 = {R.drawable.hiit1,R.drawable.hiit2,R.drawable.hiit3,R.drawable.hiit4, };
        workouts = workouts1;

        animate(image, workouts, 0, false);
    }
```

Here is animate function used above:

```
private void animate(final ImageView imageView, final int images[], final int imageIndex,
                         final boolean forever) {

        //imageView <-- The View which displays the images
        //images[] <-- Holds R references to the images to display
        //imageIndex <-- index of the first image to show in images[]
        //forever <-- If equals true then after the last image it starts all over again with the first image resulting in an infinite loop. You have been warned.

        int fadeInDuration = 500; // Configure time values here
        int timeBetween = 3000;
        int fadeOutDuration = 1000;

        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    //Visible or invisible by default - this will apply when the animation ends
        imageView.setImageResource(images[imageIndex]);

        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
        fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);

        Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // and this
        fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
        fadeOut.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);

        AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
        animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
        animation.setRepeatCount(1);
        imageView.setAnimation(animation);

        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (images.length - 1 > imageIndex) {
                    animate(imageView, images, imageIndex + 1,forever); //Calls itself until it gets to the end of the array
                }
                else {
                    if (forever == true){
                        animate(imageView, images, 0,forever);  //Calls itself to start the animation all over again in a loop if forever = true
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone tell why is this happening and how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: the execution of startWorkout(); might be too fast that the transition is not visible to you

Comment: I think that it takes a lot of time. I can see the images changing but not the button text.

Comment: What is in startWorkout(); ?

Comment: Just updated with startWorkout() and animate()